# Can't set my navigation bar title's font size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to figure out how to do this using StackOverflow and got this far:

```
[self.navController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont.systemFontSize:17 weight: UIFontWeightSemibold]}];
```

Unfortunately, I get an error underlining `UIFont.systemFontSize` that says `Bad receiver type 'CGFloat'(aka 'double')`.

How do I tweak my code so that it becomes functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off for

```
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize weight:(UIFontWeight)weight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_2);
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619027-systemfontofsize?language=objc

You want to remove the period here `UIFont.systemFontSize` and instead use `UIFont systemFontOfSize:weight:`

Rather than trying to put everything inline when setting attributes, it can sometimes be helpful to separate them out i.e.:

```
    UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIFont *navBarTitleFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f weight:UIFontWeightSemibold];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: whiteColor,
                                                                      NSFontAttributeName: navBarTitleFont
                                                                      }];
```